# Android application folder in google drive

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have an android app that reads spreadsheets from google drive and shows it to the user as a contact list.  It is design to be a phone list you can send to your team members.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ctw.cloudpeepsfree

Anyway, to get to work, all of the Google drive file names need to begin with prefix "peep:".   I have heard rumors that with the latest versions of Google Drive API, I should be able to instead put all of my app files into a special folder that only my application can read.  I was looking for some sample code or article on this subject.  Thanks...

found this blog:
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/04/more-ways-for-apps-to-write-to-drive.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use application data folder in your case, but use won't be able to list the file you put it on appdata folder: https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata

In order to put a file in the appdata folder, just set its parent to "appdata":

```
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(title);
body.setDescription(description);
body.setMimeType(mimeType);
body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId("appdata"));

service.files().insert(body).execute();
```

Comment: Yes, i think that link has the information i am looking for.  I need to test it out to see if it works as I'm reading.